# how to use 'show' and 'placement' and other attributes in bootstrap 3 popover altogether?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, popover

I have some input fields and a link in my html. I want to pop a popover on the link when any of the input fields are clicked. The codes are given below :

```
$('.name').on('click', function(){
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show');    
});
```

I get the popover, but I need to define placements and other attributes. I tried in the following way, but failed

```
$('.name').on('click', function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('show',{
        placement : 'top'
    }); 
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the following:

```
$('.name').on('click', function () {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
        placement : 'top',
        content : 'I am a popover!'
    }).popover('show');
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/1sz3ovzd/)